# Хранение XML шаблонов для генерации ответов при запросе на API

Tags: xml, api

Есть несколько различных шаблонов XML, которые необходимо генерировать на различные запросы по API. Правильным ли будет решение хранить каждый шаблон отдельно в файле и при запросе считывать из файла и генерировать ответ? Строить на лету XML библиотекой типа DOM и тому подобное мне показалось извращенным вариантом

Comment: Каковы размеры этих шаблонов и их количество? Можно же все в памяти держать. Какой язык программирования используется? Во многих языках/фреймворках есть встроенные возможности работы с шаблонами (html/xml).

Comment: Размеры небольшие, но они все разные. Кол-во 5 штук, язык программирования php